# Drupal Commerce Paypal

Tags: drupal, paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing, drupal-commerce

I have been doing quite a bit of research on payment methods, and it looks like Drupal commerce really tries to push site admins/devs towards Paypal. There are a few options that seem possible, but before I say that, these are my clients basic necessities:

- On site payment.
- International sales.

The client has a business account with Paypal and existing store with Paypal Payments Pro (WPP) with an outdated cms.

So far with Paypal I think that Payments Pro would be great, but I can not seem to find if it can handle international transactions. The other option is Paypal Payflow Link (PFL), because that is the only one that mentions international capabilities and on site payment. However, it mentions the need of a third party payment processor? I thought that this was what this is supposed to be.

What I have been reading: WPP 
- https://drupal.org/node/1902656[1] PFL 
- https://drupal.org/node/1902734[2]

Is there a Payment Method that will solve this issue better? Is Paypal my best option? How simple of a task is this to complete? At the very least, can somebody help me connect the dots a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you need with International. WPP works with several currencies and you pay whatever Paypal's going exchange rate is that day (on top of the transaction fees). For instance, we take orders in Canada. I request USD and get paid in USD, even though they pay in CAD. WPP is a little restrictive in that you can only take money [where Paypal accepts it](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_intro-outside).

The big difference is going to be that PayFlow is a gateway only, while WPP is a merchant account and gateway in one. A third party merchant account might have more options, if more currencies is more important to you.